# ES6: Populate object value with a value from another object when ID is present

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to populate the value 'discount' for a product with the discount ID value from the array `discounts`, if the respective product ID exists as a value in the Discounts object.

```
const products = [{
        id: "05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d",
        name: "SANTO - Schnürstiefelette",
        price: 199.95,
        discount: 0,
    },
    {
        id: "1b9b6c7e-c856-464c-ba64-98c9dd6733b5",
        name: "AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 - Sneaker low",
        price: 109.95,
        discount: 0,
    },
    {
        id: "f831aaf4-347a-458f-bb0c-21cf02aeac2e",
        name: "DUFF 9.0 - Sporttasche",
        price: 34.95,
        discount: 0,
    },
    {
        id: "471ad894-150b-4a2b-881c-a9a4dbc4b401",
        name: "Strickpullover",
        price: 20.99,
        discount: 0,
    },
];

const discounts = [{
        id: "5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812b5",
        name: "Christmas discount",
        productIds: ["1b9b6c7e-c856-464c-ba64-98c9dd6733b5", "f831aaf4-347a-458f-bb0c-21cf02aeac2e"],
        active: true
    },
    {
        id: "5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812e6",
        name: "Christmas discount 2",
        productIds: ["05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d"],
        active: true
    }
];
```

At the end i need it like:

```
const products = [{
        id: "05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d",
        name: "SANTO - Schnürstiefelette",
        price: 199.95,
        discount: '5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812e6',
    },
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the discounts in a `Map` and map the object with a new discount object, if necessary.

```js
var products = [{ id: "05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d", name: "SANTO - Schnürstiefelette", price: 199.95, discount: 0 }, { id: "1b9b6c7e-c856-464c-ba64-98c9dd6733b5", name: "AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 - Sneaker low", price: 109.95, discount: 0 }, { id: "f831aaf4-347a-458f-bb0c-21cf02aeac2e", name: "DUFF 9.0 - Sporttasche", price: 34.95, discount: 0 }, { id: "471ad894-150b-4a2b-881c-a9a4dbc4b401", name: "Strickpullover", price: 20.99, discount: 0 }],
    discounts = [{ id: "5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812b5", name: "Christmas discount", productIds: ["1b9b6c7e-c856-464c-ba64-98c9dd6733b5", "f831aaf4-347a-458f-bb0c-21cf02aeac2e"], active: true }, { id: "5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812e6", name: "Christmas discount 2", productIds: ["05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d"], active: true }],
    ids = discounts.reduce((m, { id, productIds }) => productIds.reduce((n, pid) => n.set(pid, id), m), new Map);

products = products.map(p => Object.assign({}, p, ids.has(p.id) && { discount: ids.get(p.id) }));

console.log(products);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform `products` array. And [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if discount exists for a product.

```js
const products = [{ id: "05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d", name: "SANTO - Schnürstiefelette", price: 199.95, discount: 0, }, { id: "1b9b6c7e-c856-464c-ba64-98c9dd6733b5", name: "AIR FORCE 1 07 LV8 - Sneaker low", price: 109.95, discount: 0, }, { id: "f831aaf4-347a-458f-bb0c-21cf02aeac2e", name: "DUFF 9.0 - Sporttasche", price: 34.95, discount: 0, }, { id: "471ad894-150b-4a2b-881c-a9a4dbc4b401", name: "Strickpullover", price: 20.99, discount: 0, }, ];
const discounts = [{ id: "5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812b5", name: "Christmas discount", productIds: ["1b9b6c7e-c856-464c-ba64-98c9dd6733b5", "f831aaf4-347a-458f-bb0c-21cf02aeac2e"], active: true }, { id: "5791ae04-a704-4f44-808b-de5ddb8812e6", name: "Christmas discount 2", productIds: ["05cdb75d-7984-4dbf-b0f4-d6532163b66d"], active: true } ];

let result = products.map(product => {
  let discount = discounts.find(item => item.productIds.includes(product.id));

  return {
    ...product,
    "discount": discount ? discount.id : product.discount
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested loop through both products and discounts array, if the product id is included inside the productIds array of any of the objects in the discounts array, assign the discount id to the product discount.

```
for (let product of products) {
  for (let discount of discounts) {
    if (discount.productIds.includes(product.id)){
      product.discount = discount.id;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.